# Current user (ASP.NET Identity) information within Generic repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, repository-pattern

I have implemented generic repository pattern over an EF Core context, for example;

```
    public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : EntityBase
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        internal TContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(TContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetById(long id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        { 
            entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        //... additional methods removed for brevity
    }
```

All my models are using an `EntityBase` class that allows me to record when the record was created and by whom, for example;

```
    public abstract class EntityBase {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        //... additional fields removed for brevity
    }
```

What are the different ways to access the current user within the repository, so I can add the user to the entity on creation;

```
        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        { 
            entity.CreatedBy = CurrentUser.Name; // TODO: get current user here?
            entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }
```

It feels like I should be able to do this via middleware and or injection.

Comment: It depends on what are you using for authentication. Are you using JWT?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Identity and cookies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you should pass user information from controller to the repository method or set CreatedBy value inside the controller instead of Repository method. Moreover , in my opinion you should avoid depend your repository to the identity and keep it simple and independent.

In other words, referencing ***HttpContext.User.Identity*** inside your repository is not a good idea,and ***HttpContext*** belog to the Presentation Layer not Data Layer.

Comment: Auditing requirements of the data mean that I need to keep record of who created and edited it.

Comment: i know what do you mean, but as i mentioned it is better pass data with your model to the repository instead of access identity(class or ...) inside repository class. With this approach in the future you can change your authentication library.